Some dash bar icons missing
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with Gnome last Tuesday. On the panel bar I have a Firefox symbol and when opening several Firefox instances the behaviour originally was that the Firefox icon stays on the docker region and I get additional red dots when several Firefox are open. Now suddenly (possibly after upgrading Firefox) I get a gear wheel symbol when opening Firefox (see picture below). Also the symbol of the app store is not shown anymore in the panel and l'm getting a gear wheel symbol instead. Other symbols like for gimp are shown correctly.


I got the Firefox icon back by copying the firefox desktop file from /snap/firefox/current to the folder ~/.local/share/applications
and
sed -i 's/Icon=\/default256.png/Icon=\/snap\/firefox\/current\/default256.png/' \
firefox.desktop

See also here: Ubuntu 22.04 firefox desktop icon
The sed command replaces Icon=/default256.png with Icon=/snap/firefox/current/default256.png in the firefox.desktop file.

I accidentally removed snapd and reinstalled it, which also solves the issue if everything else fails.

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/2041094
